# iterate over nested dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

below is a dictionary that i have create for a project. I am trying to iterate over the list values but keep getting errors

```
moo = {'dell': {'strengths': {'dell strengths': ['http://www.strategicmanagementinsight.com/swot-analyses/dell-swot-analysis.html',
    'http://www.academia.edu/3687086/Strategic_Management_case_analysis_DELL']},
  'weekness': {'dell weekness': ['http://www.strategicmanagementinsight.com/swot-analyses/dell-swot-analysis.html',
    'http://www.123helpme.com/dell-strength-and-weakness-view.asp%3Fid%3D164569']}},
 'ibm': {'strengths': {'ibm strengths': ['http://www.forbes.com/sites/stevedenning/2011/07/10/why-did-ibm-survive/',
    'http://www.strategicmanagementinsight.com/swot-analyses/ibm-swot-analysis.html']},
  'weekness': {'ibm weekness': ['http://www.quora.com/IBM/What-are-the-weaknesses-of-IBM',
    'http://www.marketingteacher.com/ibm-swot/']}}}

for k in moo.keys():
#base.add_sheet(k)
    for sk in moo[k].keys():
    #print sk
        for mk in moo[k][sk].keys():
            moo[k][sk][mk] = googlelinks(mk,2)
            for v in moo[k][sk][mk].items():
                print v
```

Error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'
```

I am doing something terribly wrong here. Please help

Comment: And what does `googlelinks()` return then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like `googlelinks()` is returning a list, not a dictionary. You just iterate over that using `for v in moo[k][sk][mk]:`. No need for `items()` unless you're using a dictionary in particular.

EDIT: it's unclear why you're using `keys()` for most of the code and them `items()` later. The `items()` function will return both the key and the value for a given dictionary item, which lets you simplify your code greatly. You can eliminate nested calls like `moo[k][sk][mk]` by doing something like this instead (thanks Martijn):

```
for k, v in moo.items():  # v = moo[k]
#base.add_sheet(k)
    for sk, sv in v.items():  # sv = v[sk] = moo[k][sk]
    #print sk
        for mk, mv in sv.items():  # mv = sv[mk] = v[sk][mk] = moo[k][sk][mk]
            sv[mk] = googlelinks(mk,2)
            for gv in sv[mk]:
                print gv
```

On another note, you may want to give your variables less cryptic names, so your code is easier to follow. Ideally, we should know from reading your variable names what's stored in each dictionary.

Comment: The OP would be better of looping over *values* or *items*, not keys; that way the OP can assign directly back but also use the actual nested dictionary.

Comment: @MartijnPieters what is OP?

Comment: [What is an OP when referring to Stack Exchange?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253162)

Comment: @RaghavShaligram OP stand for original poster, in this case you.  It is commonly used as a pronoun instead of the gender specfic prounons his/her.

Comment: I have iterating over the keys since i want to write out names of sheets and rows in the worksheets. Let me still try the code. Looks simpler

Comment: @RaghavShaligram `items()` returns key/value pairs, so you can just grab the keys from the code above (`k, sk, mk`) and use them how you like.